# Android Alarm manager cancelled after reboot device or application kill from background

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am developing an alarm app. When I am set alarm and reboot device alarm is  not ringing and it is happening  in some specific device (xiomi note 4 and samsung s5).

My manifest for register receiver:

```
 <receiver
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":remote"
        android:name="com.electrovese.alarm.AlarmReceiver.AliveAllAlarmRecever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="AliveAllAlarmRecever"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Thanks.

Comment: "when i am set alarm and reboot device alarm is not ringing" - That's how alarms work; they don't persist upon reboot. You need to reset your alarms when the device boots.

Comment: You use the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` to reset the alarm. Alarm will always be canceled off after reboot. Use the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver to reset the alarms with correct requestCodes.

Comment: @NicholasTee   First Thanks for reply.  After reboot device  broadcast receiver also not get called on reboot and if i am kill app from background then also not get called then how can i reset alarm with correct request code  on reboot device and kill app from background ? i have tested it on XIOMI note 4 and samsung s5.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to tell `Android` that you have some receiver to run when the device restarts. You can do it like this:

Step 1: Create the Receiver:

```
class AlarmRebootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action.equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // oh well, device rebooted. do what you have to do here
    }
}
```

After that, just register to manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".background.AlarmRebootReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Done!

Answer (score -2):

you should check on your app in Autostart in Xiaomi devices:

> Settings -> Permissions -> Autostart